# Flutter Native Timezone library can not build on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-native-timezone

I am trying to get the LocalTimeZone in my Flutter app. For this purpose, I used `'package:timezone/timezone.dart'` with a conjunction of `'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';`. But when I install the `flutter_native_timezone` v.2.0.0. I got an error in Android build like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_native_timezone' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My Kotlin plugin version is 1.8.10. I tried to downgrade it to 1.5.20, but same result. I tried with the lower version of the library but the error still persists.

flutter doctor output looks like this:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm64, locale en-BG)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [flutter_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_timezone) which is a fork of the repository you were using initially using

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I do not need the time zone. I need to run the library because I need the location. 
I need to determinate the hardcoded string in the getLocation here: 
`tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('Europe/Sofia'));`
and it seem the in Flutter this lib is the only way that I found.

Comment: OK, i see. Maybe you could try flutter_timezone which is a fork of the repository you were using initially here is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_timezone

Comment: Thanks, It seems promising I will try and tell

Comment: This works, edit your answer with this library in order to mark it as assessed.

Answer (score 0):

try flutter_timezone, then use [enter link description here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/timezone)

```
tz.initializeTimeZones();
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(""));
```